# Viewing source output of a MediaWiki template

Tags: templates, mediawiki, generated

Is there a way to get the mediawiki code that is generated by a template? I want to go on to Wikipedia, use a citation template, and copy the generated wiki code to my wiki that doesn't have those citation templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a way -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ExpandTemplates

Note that this is provided by an extension, so if you want this ability on your own MediaWiki installation you may need to install it: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ExpandTemplates